# DevForce with custom property

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, devforce

I want to add a custom property to an existing Entity to take advantage of DevForce Validation. This property is not be saved to database, just works as a "helper". I used StringLengthVerifier as follow:

```
[StringLengthVerifier(MaxValue = 20, MinValue = 5, IsRequired = true)]
public string RepeatPassword
{
    get
    {
        return _repeatPassword;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_repeatPassword != value)
        {
            _repeatPassword = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RepeatPassword"));
        }
    }
}
```

When I save, I get an EntityServerSaveException with information: RepeatPassword is required.

If I set IsRequired = false, the error gone and the save action works well but if I do it, the validation will not work when the value of the property is null or empty.

Any hints?